# modification of type namespace inside function

Tags: c++

I migrate from one API to newer version and there is very common situation that old classes have only new namespace, like this:

Lib::ReadingData::Reader -> New::Lib::ReadingData::Reader.

I am trying to write a function that will allow easier migration using this fact, but unfortunately I am not sure if it is possible and how to do it.

```
namespace Lib::ReadingData
{
    struct Reader;
}

namespace New::Lib::ReadingData
{
    struct Reader;
}

template<typename T>
auto ToNewLib(T from) // T == Lib::ReadingData::Reader
{
    New::T to {nullptr}; //I want to 'magically' add New namespace at the beggining of type name.
    
    //Some needed operations
    
    return to;
}

template<typename T>
auto ToOldLib(T from) //T == New::Lib::ReadingData::Reader
{
    to {nullptr}; //Need to remove New:: from T
    
    //Some needed operations
    
    return to;
}

int main()
{
    Lib::ReadingData::Reader reader{};
    New::Lib::ReadingData::Reader newReader = ToNewLib(reader);
    Lib::ReadingData::Reader oldReader = ToOldLib(newReader);
}
```

Comment: Does ```#define Lib::ReadingData::Reader New::Lib::ReadingData::Reader``` works ?

Comment: @Gaston That's not valid syntax since C++11 and doesn't do what you expect it to before that.

Comment: Naah the only thing I can think of is to write a script to autogenerate these conversion functions for you.

Comment: I am not able to migrate at one time due to the project being too big for that, so this type of macro is out. 

Besides, there are relatively many different classes / functions etc to change, so I am looking for a generic solution.

Comment: No, namespaces don't work this way.